# Lambda function over n columns

Tags: pandas

Let's say I have a dataframe with n columns (col1_a, col1_b, col2_a, col2_b,  ... col34_a, col34_b).

I want to be able to do a lambda function on columns with similar names. So col1_a and col1_b would go through a function and create column col1_c. In the example below the lambda function just adds the two columns. I have n columns so I would like to not have to manually reference each column name.

Is this possible with pandas?

Input:

```
    col1_a   col1_b   col2_a  col2_b  ... col34_a   col34_b
1   5        2        3       4           9         2
2   2        4        1       2           3         4
3   4        1        2       5           4         3
```

Output:

```
    col1_a   col1_b   col1_c  col2_a  col2_b   col2_c  ... col34_a   col34_b   col34_c
1   5        2        7       3       4        7            9         2        11
2   2        4        6       1       2        3            3         4        7
3   4        1        5       5       4        9            3         5        8
```

Comment: kindly share an example of the function and expected output

Comment: `df['new_col'] = df.apply(func, axis=1)`

Comment: I think you can use `filter` or the `re.module` you can also use `str.contains` on columns. as sammy said, please provide an intended output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If possible grouping by values of columns names before first `_` then aggregate `sum` by columns, add suffix and last append to original with sorting columns names:

```
df1 = df.groupby(lambda x: x.split('_')[0], axis=1).sum().add_suffix('_c')
df = df.join(df1).sort_index(axis=1)
print (df)
   col1_a  col1_b  col1_c  col2_a  col2_b  col2_c  col34_a  col34_b  col34_c
1       5       2       7       3       4       7        9        2       11
2       2       4       6       1       2       3        3        4        7
3       4       1       5       2       5       7        4        3        7
```

Comment: This is a very elegant solution. Let's say that I had other columns in this dataframe labeled 'hat' and 'tree'. Is there a way to do this sum on columns pairs ONLY starting with 'col'? Seems like I would need to filter, but I can't seem to get it to work.

Maybe the columns should have been multindex...

Comment: @DavidGlasser - You are right, you can filter columns before processing like `df1 = df.filter(regex='^col').groupby(lambda x: x.split('_')[0], axis=1).sum().add_suffix('_c')`

Answer (score 0):

Alternative answer using `for loop` and `lambda`:

```
# Import libraries
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Create DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'col1_a': [1,2,3,4,5],
    'col1_b': [6,7,8,9,5],
    'col2_a': [.1,.2,.3,.4,.5],
    'col2_b': [.6,.7,.8,.9,.5],
})

# Calculate
for i in range(int(len(df.columns)/2)):
    df['col'+str(i+1)+'_c'] = df.apply(lambda x: x['col'+str(i+1)+'_a'] + x['col'+str(i+1)+'_b'], axis=1)
```

Output

```
print(df)

   col1_a  col1_b  col2_a  col2_b  col1_c  col2_c
0       1       6     0.1     0.6     7.0     0.7
1       2       7     0.2     0.7     9.0     0.9
2       3       8     0.3     0.8    11.0     1.1
3       4       9     0.4     0.9    13.0     1.3
4       5       5     0.5     0.5    10.0     1.0
```